# <attribute> cannot be resolved as a member of <bean>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a bean:

```
package controller.types;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Test
{

    static List<MainTableRow> rows;

    public Test()
    {
        rows = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static List<MainTableRow> getRows()
    {
        return rows;
    }

    public static void setRows(List<MainTableRow> rows)
    {
        Test.rows = rows;
    }

}
```

And my xhtml page is:

```
    <h:form>
        <p:fileUpload
            fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"
            mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="false" update="messages"
            sizeLimit="10000000" fileLimit="3" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xls)$/"  style="font-size: 14px"/>

        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

        <p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="mainTableRow" value="#{test.rows}" style="font-size: 14px">
            <f:facet name="header">
            Main Table
        </f:facet>

            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="Index">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.index}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="Query">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.index}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="S1">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.index}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="S2">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.index}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="S3">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.index}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="S9">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.index}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="Uygunluk">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.index}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="Kural">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.index}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="Kaynak">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.index}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="Query Type">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.index}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="" headerText="User Intent">
                <h:outputText value="#{mainTableRow.index}" />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>

    </h:form>
```

At line `<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="mainTableRow" value="#{test.rows}" style="font-size: 14px">` it gives error:

**rows cannot be resolved as a member of test**

What is the reason?

Comment: Those methods are `static`. They are not members of the bean. Make them instance methods or rethink your design if you can't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness, [the documentation for managed beans](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaqm.html) states the following for bean properties

> As with all JavaBeans components, a property consists of a private
>   data field and a set of accessor methods, as shown by this code:

```
private Integer userNumber = null;
...
public void setUserNumber(Integer user_number) {
    userNumber = user_number;
}
public Integer getUserNumber() {
    return userNumber;
}
```

In your case, you were using static methods as accessors/mutators. This won't work because those methods are not members of an object (bean), they are members of the class. The application won't be able to resolve them as members of your `test` bean.

The solution is to modify your class so that you are no longer working with `static` fields and methods.

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Test
{

    List<MainTableRow> rows;

    public Test()
    {
        rows = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<MainTableRow> getRows()
    {
        return rows;
    }

    public void setRows(List<MainTableRow> rows)
    {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

}
```